# SQL SUM of attributes with same value and a Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, conditional-statements

If i have this table

```
MOVS (accounts, value, date, tipomov) VALUES ('12345678901', 3105.77, '2018-01-20 09:15:44', 0)
MOVS (accounts, value, date, tipomov) VALUES ('45678901234', 1897.02, '2019-11-20 09:25:44', 0)
MOVS (accounts, value, date, tipomov) VALUES ('12345678901', 22.50,   '2019-03-22 07:50:44', 1)
MOVS (accounts, value, date, tipomov) VALUES ('12345678901', 1030.40, '2019-04-21 19:15:44', 1)
MOVS (accounts, value, date, tipomov) VALUES ('89012345678', 1200.55, '2019-01-20 11:15:44', 0)
MOVS (accounts, value, date, tipomov) VALUES ('45678901234', 300,     '2018-12-24 08:15:44', 1)
```

I want to Identify accounts whose sum  of value of tipomov 0 is greater than those of tipomov 1 in the month of December 2018. I tried GROUP BY and other clauses but cant seem to get it right.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select sum(value)
from movs
where tipomov = 0
having sum(value) > (select sum(value)
                     from movs
                     where tipomov = 1
                       and date >= date '2018-12-01'
                       and date < date '2019-01-01')
```

The date range condition is standard SQL, but not all DBMS product support that, so you might need to adjust that to the DBMS you are using.